# Are Amadeus Hotel Queries Rate Limited?

Tags: rate-limiting, amadeus

Expedia Hotel pricing queries are rate limited. Is the Amadeus API /shopping/hotel-offers - FIND HOTELS also rate limited in terms of number of API queries per hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Self-Service Amadeus APIs for the test environment there is a [limited number of free monthly calls](https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing) per API.

The platform has the following rate limits: in the **test environment** you cannot do more than 1 request per 100ms (10 transactions per second per user) and in **production** no more than 1 request per 50ms (20 transactions per second per user).